# Redirecting to Not Show Method after Model Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a question involving the default routes in Rails 3.1. I have a default scaffold at the moment. Upon creating a item using the new method, I would like it to redirect to a different method than show. How can I go about doing this? (If code would be nice, please say so! I figured it would be unneccessary since its a default scaffold but I can supply it).

Answer (score 0):

Change the scaffold method to redirect somewhere else, like back to the index, e.g.:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to entry_url }
end
```

(Assuming an `Entry` model, obviously.)